# XPath returns different results using Chrome Plugin and Python

Tags: python, html, parsing, web-scraping, lxml

I'm struggling to use XPath on HTML Code finding the information i need.

I've tried several queries but they keep returning an empty list in python. So I installed a chrome plugin to check whether my queries are wrong, turns out they're not, so i am fully confused by now. Is my whole approach wrong or am I missing something here?

```
import requests
from lxml import html


#specify the url
base_url = 'https://www.lolesports.com/en_US/na- 
lcs/na_2018_summer/schedule/regular_season/2'

#query the website and return the html to the variable ‘html_code’
html_code = requests.get(base_url)

tree = html.fromstring(html_code.content)
my_nodes = tree.xpath('//a[@id="ember9461"]') ## here it keeps returning an empty list
```

Tried several queries which all do not work, except the broad wildcard "//*" which i can not parse further.

I want to parse the links provided in href at (for example) 'a id="ember9461" ....... /a'  for every game in a week. So it would be best to return a list with all these links or at least something containing the links, that i can further parse. But as I said before, I keep getting an empty array, although it's the correct XPath shown from the XPath Plugin from Chrome.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

It's my first question here, I'll return to add screenshots if i find out how : )

EDIT: It was asked for the output: Well, i do not get an error, just the described empty list for "my_nodes". I'm using PyCharm 8.13.

```
my_nodes = {list}<class 'list'>: []
```

I would expect anything, but an empty list, since the queries are working with the XPath Plugin.

Here is a screenshot explaining the problem:

[query with XPath Plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okiyq.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. ~You will get a better response if you include the exact inputs and outputs you have used, to make it easier to determine what might be wrong. There's advice about how to write questions at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  Use text rater than screenshots, so othr people can work with them!

Comment: Ok, i added the output/result of my_nodes and further added a screenshot for further clarification hopefully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may need a method like selenium where you can scroll to generate all the links and allow time for their presence

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from urllib.parse import urljoin
base = 'https://www.lolesports.com'
url = 'https://www.lolesports.com/en_US/na-lcs/na_2018_summer/schedule/regular_season/1'
d = webdriver.Chrome()
d.get(url)
WebDriverWait(d, 20).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".throbber-loader")))
copyright = WebDriverWait(d, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".copyright-text")))
d.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", copyright)
WebDriverWait(d,5).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.ember-view')))
soup = bs(d.page_source,'lxml')
links = [urljoin(base,link.get('href')) for link in soup.select('.ember-view') if link.get('href')]
print(len(links))
print(links)
d.quit()
```

---

Selenium only:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from urllib.parse import urljoin

base = 'https://www.lolesports.com'
url = 'https://www.lolesports.com/en_US/na-lcs/na_2018_summer/schedule/regular_season/1'
d = webdriver.Chrome()
d.get(url)
WebDriverWait(d, 20).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".throbber-loader")))
copyright = WebDriverWait(d, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".copyright-text")))
d.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", copyright)
elems = WebDriverWait(d,5).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.ember-view[href]')))

links = []
for elem in elems:
    links.append(urljoin(base,elem.get_attribute('href')))

print(len(links))
print(links)
d.quit()
```

Comment: You are my Santa Claus! It's working! Whole different approach though and i need to get behind that code. After installing Chromedriver and setting it up your code delivers the links i am looking for. Thanks a lot! I upvoted, but apparently it's not shown yet due to my beginner-reputation : )

Comment: I used css selectors instead of xpath. I waited for the loading spinner to disappear, scrolled to bottom of page, waiting for all the elements you were after to appear (using a css class selector) then limited to just those classes with an href in the comprehension. For some reason the python bs4 implementation doesn't seem to like a more direct css selector of .emberview[href]. Technically you don't need bs4 at all as it can all be done with selenium.

Answer (score 0):

and Merry X-Mas to you too :)

As far as I know, your syntax is correct and actually returns something. The thing is, it does not return something that can be parsed with your XPath query (check html_content) to see for yourself. This explains why it returns an empty list.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Any idea on how i can extract the href info given by the html code? Do i need another approach?

Comment: You need another approach. I don't see much HTML code in what is returned by

     html_code = requests.get(base_url)